# Computing a gradient. Error in func(x, ...) : unused argument (x)

Tags: r, compiler-errors, gradient

I always get the error Error in func(x, ...) : unused argument (x) while computing the gradient of a function even though I use all the arguments.

The function is

```
library(numDeriv)
prob_a = 0.2124352
prob_b = c(0.3160622, 0.3416811, 0.3672999, 0.3929188, 0.4185377, 0.4441566, 0.4697755, 0.4953944, 0.5210132, 0.5466321)
prob_c = c(0.002590674, 0.025331031, 0.048071387, 0.070811744, 0.093552101, 0.116292458, 0.139032815, 0.161773172, 0.184513529, 0.207253886)
f = function(c, b) c * log(c/(b * prob_a))
grad(func = f, c = prob_c[1], b = prob_b[1])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Already worked through `?numDeriv::grad`?